# reflection to invoke methods of unknown property types

Tags: c#, nested-class, system.reflection

I want to call the generic method, 'get_', for each property, `IEnumerable<class>`,  of my view model class to avoid creating lengthy switch statements that explicitly get each list...  Does anyone know how to get the object type and method generically?

```
    foreach (var prop in vm.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes<ExportAttribute>().Any()))
    {
        var objType = ??;
        var method = objType.GetMethod(<by name>);
        var list = method.Invoke(prop, null);
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: `var objType = prop.PropertyType`

Comment: It's not clear what you mean here - why not just use `PropertyInfo.GetGetMethod()`?

Answer (score 4):

I would use something like:

```
foreach (var prop in vm.GetType()
                       .GetProperties()
                       .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes<ExportAttribute>().Any()))
{
    var list = (IEnumerable) prop.GetValue(vm, null);
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Now `item` will be typed as `object`... but you can't really do better than that anyway. Your "do something" code can't use any members of the element type anyway, because it could be any type.

If, on the other hand, you know that every property will be something implementing `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` will in each case have a common base type, then due to the generic covariance of `IEnumerable<T>` introduced in .NET 4, you can write:

```
foreach (var prop in vm.GetType()
                       .GetProperties()
                       .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes<ExportAttribute>().Any()))
{
    var list = (IEnumerable<BaseType>) prop.GetValue(vm, null);
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then you can access `item.PropertyDeclaredInBaseType`.

Note that I've changed the target of the call to `vm` instead of `null`, as presumably you want those *instance* properties...

Comment: Why can I see the properties of item in the watch when I set a break point but can't access them?  I guess I don't under stand why it could be any type?   What if all the properties I am iterating through are of the same base type?  I only want to access the base type anyhow... it shows the type as object { blah.blah.blah } giving the full class name???

Comment: @midohioboarder: Then you should cast to `IEnumerable<BaseType>` instead, assuming you're using .NET 4. You didn't mention anything about that in the question, unfortunately.